# Extract drawn shape from Image in flask

Tags: python, image, flask, crop

I am trying to extract a drawn image, which should be extracted after pressing Clip button on my flask web app. I am not able to combine the code, from my web application to python script.
This is my python script which is still incompleteenter code here

```
from flask import Flask, render_template,request
import os
import cv2
import argparse

###################### READING IMAGE ###########################
img = cv2.imread('static/pics/img.png',0)
###################### UPLOADING PIC ############################
app = Flask(__name__)

picFolder = os.path.join('static', 'pics')
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = picFolder

###############################################################

def shape_selection(event, x, y, flags, param):
    # grab references to the global variables
    global ref_point, crop

    # if the left mouse button was clicked, record the starting
    # (x, y) coordinates and indicate that cropping is being performed
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        ref_point = [(x, y)]

        # check to see if the left mouse button was released
    elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        # record the ending (x, y) coordinates and indicate that
        # the cropping operation is finished
        ref_point.append((x, y))

        # draw a rectangle around the region of interest
        cv2.rectangle(img, ref_point[0], ref_point[1], (0, 255, 0), 2)
    ####################### FLASK ###################################


@app.route("/")
def index():
    UPLOAD_FOLDER='static/pics/';
    pic1 = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], 'img.png')
    pic2 = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], 'mask1.png')
    return render_template("index.html", user_image=pic1,mask_image=pic2)


@app.route("/bonus")
def bonus():
   # pic1 = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], 'img.png')
    image = cv2.imread('static/pics/img.png', 0)
    clone = image.copy()
    cv2.namedWindow("image")
    pic1= cv2.setMouseCallback("image", shape_selection)
    return render_template("bonus.html", user_image=pic1)


app.run(debug=True)
```

This is my HTML file in which I want to view both files, original and cropped

Comment: `cv2` is for desktop applications, not for web page applications. I don't understand what you try to do. If you want to draw shape in web browser then you have to use JavaScript for this,not `cv2`. If you want to draw in `cv2` window then use some key/button in this window to finish it - but it will not work with web page.

Comment: BTW: `cv2` can display only on monitor connected to computer which runs `cv2` - if you put your code on server then `cv2` will try to display window on monitor connected to server, not on client monitor, so it is useless for you.

Comment: BTW: you say `This is my HTML file` but I see only Python code, not HTML file.